# Windows 7 dualscreen wallpaper?

Tags: windows-7

So, I've got a killer dual screen wallpaper that stretches across both monitors.  The question is...when I lock my computer or if I logoff and log back in.  It shows the default wallpaper on my left screen and leaves my right screen black...until I'm logged in then it shows my dual screen wallpaper.

Is there any ways to override the default wallpaper on the login screen?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [Ultimate Windows Tweaker](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-v2-a-tweak-ui-for-windows-7-vista) to set the wallpaper for when you're not logged in.

Comment: I'd vote you up, b/c UWT is SWEET!  But, I don't have enough cred yet.

UWT did allow me to switch the default wallpaper.  Thanks for that!  But, it still only shows on 1 of my 2 monitors.  Anyone know how to tweak that?